# ssh 3des private key encrypt and decrypt

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

i have converted my ssh private key with 3des encryption

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 des3 -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa.old -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

how do I remove encryption and get the old key?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't deleted the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.old`, that's your old key without passphrase ("unencrypted").

Otherwise, to remove a passphrase from the keyfile just use the command

`openssl pkey -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -out ~/.ssh/id_rsa_unencrypted`

You will be prompted for the passphrase.

Comment: this is not about the passphrase, I need to remove 3DES encryption...

Comment: The command you posted encrypted `~/.ssh/id_rsa.old` with 3DES using a passphrase as key.  OpenSSL must have prompted you for that passphrase when you ran that command.

Comment: What is printed out when you type `head -n 1 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` ?